# Vite config files and aliases

Tags: import, configuration, alias, vite

I have files I want to import based on environment. Currently I import it into the file like this

```
import { myConfig } from "../config/my-config";
```

however I would like to do it based on environment import the correct config file based on environment.

So ideally I would have (they could be json and not TS)

**

```
my-config-dev.ts
my-config-staging.ts
my-config-prod.ts
```

**

How can I alias the above import based on the environment?